# <machinekey> in web.config and machine.config

Tags: asp.net, machinekey

If the machine.config file does not define any  section, nor does any web.config file, does it default to AutoGenerate option?

Thanks

Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the AutoGenerate setting is the default setting for both decryptionKey and validationKey.

> "AutoGenerate, IsolateApps" - Specifies that the key is automatically generated. *This is the default value.* The AutoGenerate modifier specifies that ASP.NET generates a random key and stores it in the Local Security Authority (LSA). The IsolateApps modifier specifies that ASP.NET generates a unique encrypted key for each application using the application ID of each application.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx